# У больших пректов бывает sitmap.xml?

Tags: sitemap

Доброе утро, собственно тема и есть вопрос, например у АВИТО есть или нет? ведь если есть то у таких проектов сколько весит то sitemap, целый сервер получается занимает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видимо нет
http://www.avito.ru/sitemap.xml

А вобще вы видно немного не правильно понимаете значение этого файла, в него обычно пихают свежие, не проидексированные ссылки.
Sitemap.xml обычно делают динамически обновляемым с лимитом ссылок.
На сколько я помню кто то писал на серче, что боты сканируют определенное количество первых ссылок в sitemap.xml, а остальные пропускают, если он слишком большой.

Ну а для проектов типа авита и тому подобных, ситемап попросту не нужен, так страницы и так залетают в индекс сразу же после их создания.

Comment: Цитирую - "так страницы и так залетают в индекс сразу же после их создания.", а как сразу после создания индексируется? Ведь мы создаем посты бывает так что неделю ждешь это еще при sitemap, хотя и еще указываешь чтоб роботы каждый день заходили

Comment: Такие сайт робот ПС не посещает, он там живет и следовательно все новое сразу же в индекс влетает. Это трастовые сайты, им не нужно думать о том как загнать страничку в индекс.

Это у нас с вами страницы залетают через месяц, а там сразу же.

Цитата: "а как сразу после создания индексируется?"
Если вы про яндекс, то быстроробот добавляет новую страницу в серп.

Comment: есть проект, и туда думаю стоит ли писать sitemap или нет не могу решатся, вот здесь я писал вопрос http://hashcode.ru/questions/351068/sitemap-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9. И последний вопрос а как пригласить роботов жить у себя в сервере?

Comment: Создать его стоит, он в любом случае не помешает.
А чтобы роботы на сайте жили, нужно постоянно добавлять новый и уникальный контент. Если часто обновлять будете, то и робот часто заходить будет.

Comment: @webphp Спасибо за советы!

Answer (score 2):

у авито сайтмап лежит в директории 
https://www.avito.ru/sitemap/index.xml

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?